# What happens to $f(x) = \left\lceil \dfrac{x}{a} \right\rceil \cdot a$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits

Consider the function $f(x) = \left\lceil \dfrac{x}{a} \right\rceil \cdot a~~~$ 
where $a \in R$ and $a \neq 0 $. Now let us say we are interested in the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. It seems like $f(x) \sim x$, but I'm trying to come up with a formal proof. For an illustration, refer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%3D%20ceiling%28x%2Fa%29*a%20%2C%20x%3D-10000%20to%20x%3D10000%2C%20a%3D50).

Comment: Start with $\frac{x}{a}\leq \left \lceil \frac{x}{a} \right \rceil \leq \frac{x}{a}+1$

Comment: Doesn't "converge to $x$" simply mean the limit diverges?

Comment: @AndrewChin What I'm trying to say is, for the case when x>>a, what is f(x)?

Comment: It is a step function with values in $\{na : n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: The statemeht that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ converges to $x$ is non-sensical. There are other ways to write it, though.  It is not true that $f(x)-x\to 0.$ However, it is true that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x\to 1$ which is often written as $f(x)\sim x.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I've corrected the statement.

Comment: You can always get $f(x) - x$ to be almost as large a $a$ by for any $M$ as large as you like and $n$ an integer $n>M$, taking $x= n*a +  \epsilon$ for a very tiny $\epsilon$. Then $\frac xa=n+a \epsilon$ and $[\frac xa]=n+ 1$ and $[\frac xa]a=na + a = x-\epsilon +a$.  So $f(x)-x=a-\epsilon$. ... the thing is the ratio of $a$ to $x$ because less significant for large values of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the rule

$$t\le\lceil t\rceil<t+1$$ you deduce

$$1\le\frac{f(x)}x<1+\frac ax$$ and this squeezes to $1$.

The answer is similar for $a<0$.

Comment: The inequalities are not true when $a <0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac xa \le \lceil \frac xa \rceil < \frac xa + 1$

$x \le \lceil \frac xa \rceil*a < x + a$.

And this will be true for all $x$. But we can never say the difference $\lceil \frac xa \rceil*a$ and $x$ ever decreases absolutely.

I think what you are trying to say is that $f(x)\approx x$ with an *absolute* margin of error of $a$.  But as $x$ gets very large that margin of error becomes less significant.

$1= \lim \frac xx \le \lim \frac {\lceil \frac xa \rceil*a}x < \lim \frac {x+a}x = 1$

So $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {\lceil \frac xa \rceil*a}x=1$

And $f(x)\approx x$ as $x$ gets large.  But it doesn't make sense to talk of the *limit* of $f(x)$ approaching $g(x)$.  As $x\to \infty$ it makes no sense to talk of a $x$ being a variable in $g(x)$.  Also $|f(x) -g(x)|\not \to 0$.

For any $a - \epsilon$ where $0< \epsilon < a$ we can always find large values of $x$ where $|\lceil \frac xa \rceil*a -x | >a-\epsilon$.